# Very short story - passengers on faster-than-light ship watch old broadcasts of the Howdy Doody show

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, speed-of-light, xkcd

[This **xkcd** "What If?"](http://what-if.xkcd.com/47/) reminded me of a short story I read, maybe in a compilation of Golden Age SF stories by the likes of Henry Kuttner and Fritz Leiber.  It was just a few pages long.  A group of rich old geezers are passengers on one of the first faster-than-light ships to leave Earth.  The last few sentences of the story describe them gathering around a TV set to watch TV signals that left Earth in the '50s, which the ship has caught up with---it's an episode of "The Howdy Doody Show" that the old guys remember from childhood but thought they would never see again (since it was from the era of live broadcasting before videotape).

Answer (score 7):

And, of course, after I post a bounty, I find some references. It seems this is likely "What Time is It?" by Jack Haldeman II.

[This Straight Dope message board post](https://boards.straightdope.com/t/in-the-dustbin-of-our-cultural-history/927703/895):

> There’s a science fiction story that postulates that the first use of faster than light travel is to carry aging baby boomers far enough out into space to see “Howdy Doody” and other shows that were broadcast live and not preserved: “What Time is It?” by Jack Haldeman II (Joe’s brother).

[This blog comment](http://davidbrin.blogspot.com/2020/07/more-spaaaace-news.html?showComment=1594045291054#c3085436988845237841):

> There's a story called "What Time Is It?" by Jack Haldeman https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53469 - FTL is used to go far enough away from Earth so that aging Baby Boomers can see episodes of Howdy Doody again.

And user14111 found a link to an archive.org copy of [*Vertex Volume 2 Number 6*](https://archive.org/details/Vertex_v02n06_1975-02/page/n11/mode/2up) where the story appears:

> The men were crowded around a large wooden box. It had a three inch screen with a magnifying glass in front of it. They were watching the fuzzy television images that had left the Earth years and years ago— long before video tape had been around to preserve the signals. Some of the men clutched old television schedules; some wore hats with ears on them. A freckled-faced puppet was dancing on the screen while a clown squirted seltzer water.
> All together now.
> Hey kids! What time is it?

Comment: If anyone can get the book text, I'll happily let you copy over what I have and give you the bounty.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/Vertex_v02n06_1975-02/page/n11/mode/2up

Comment: @user14111: I did not see that. :) Do you want to post an answer? Or should we just improve PMar's anwer?

Comment: Do that or improve your own answer. My work is done here.

Comment: “FTL is used to go far enough away from Earth so that aging Baby Boomers” Ok, boomers.

Comment: Since I can't self-award the bounty, I'll give it to PMar for having led us to the right answer, assuming no one else posts a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

The title of the story is "What Time Is It?".  Sorry, don't recall the author.

Comment: There is a story of that title by Jack Haldeman which is collected in an anthology called TV 2000 so that sounds like a good candidate. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53469

Comment: Can you describe why you think this would be a good match.

Comment: It's a story about TV and it's in an anthology about TV.

Comment: There are [4 short stories](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=what+time+is+it&type=Fiction+Titles) with that name - which one do you mean?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Definitely not the Elam story, described in [this unaccepted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64998/old-time-travel-story-called-what-time-is-it/64999#64999). Not the Asimov, that's a [*Black Widowers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Widowers) story. If it's one of those four, it's probably the Haldeman.

Comment: Haldeman's "What Time Is It?" seems to fit the "very short" part of the description, apparently it's all on p. 12 of [*Vertex*, February 1975](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61864+c). Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of that.

Comment: @Gallifreyan see my first comment.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The [ISFDB page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV:_2000#Part_III:_The_Consequences_of_TV) for that anthology indicates that the theme of Haldeman's "What Time Is It" is "Nostalgia", a good sign. On the other hand, Kuttner and Leiber are not represented in that anthology.

Comment: [This Review](http://dreamingaboutotherworlds.blogspot.com/2013/03/review-tv-2000-by-isaac-asimov-charles.html): "Haldeman has another story in the volume, the very brief What Time Is It?, which imagines a use for faster than light travel to indulge the nostalgic feelings of wealthy men who yearn for the television programs of their youth."

Comment: That's it, for sure.